# appending a checkmark when checkmarked and remove when not

Tags: jquery, checkbox

The selection works but the checkmarks that suppose to appear don't work as I want them to.
I tried using .remove() but it didn't do what I wanted.

It will make more sense from the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ftwvax1t/

```
if (!$('#reg_option_1_check').is('.checked')) {   $('#reg_option_1').addClass('checked').append('<span id="checkmark"><div id="circle"></div><div id="stem"></div><div id="kick"></div></span>');    }
else {  $('#reg_option_1').removeClass('checked');   }

$('#reg_option_1,#reg_option_2').on('click', function () {
    $('.registration_form_option').not(this).removeClass('checked');
    $(this).addClass('checked').append('<span id="checkmark"><div id="circle"></div><div id="stem"></div><div id="kick"></div></span>');
    $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $('#'+this.id+'_check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="registration_form_option" id="reg_option_1"> Individual </div>      
<div class="registration_form_option" id="reg_option_2">Business  </div>      

<input type="checkbox" id="reg_option_1_check" name="reg_option_1_check" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="reg_option_2_check" name="reg_option_2_check" value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier with some markup changes like

```
<div class="registration_form_option reg_option" id="reg_option_1">Individual</div>
<div class="registration_form_option reg_option" id="reg_option_2">Business</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="reg_option_1_check" name="reg_option_1_check" class="reg_option_check" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="reg_option_2_check" name="reg_option_2_check" class="reg_option_check" value="2" />
```

then

```
$('.registration_form_option').append('<span class="checkmark"><div class="circle"></div><div class="stem"></div><div class="kick"></div></span>');

$('.reg_option_check').filter(':checked').each(function () {
    $('#' + this.id.replace('_check', '')).addClass('checked')
});

var $checks = $('.reg_option_check');
var $opts = $('.reg_option').on('click', function () {
    $opts.not(this).removeClass('checked');
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    var $check = $('#' + this.id + '_check').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('checked'));
    $checks.not($check).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3vaaru4m/)

Comment: i only one selected at a time!